# SQL join and count from different tables

Tags: sql

Basically i have two tables one being doctor the second being appointments, i want to count the appointments made for each doctor but also include any doctors in the list which didn't have any appointments so far i have come up with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT doctor.doctor_id
              , sum(case when appt_date > 0 then 1 else 0 end) AppointmentCount 
FROM appointment,doctor JOIN doctor d 
WHERE appointment.doctor_id = d.doctor_id 
group by doctor_id;
```

this prints out each doctor id but makes it so the count for each doctor is exactly the same whereas i want them to have different values based on how many appointments have been made.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. Also: **mixing** the two styles is **definitely** not a good idea!

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `distinct` keyword (note that you are using group by). Avoid using Join in `where` clause; Try using `on`.

`Left Join` shall give you the expected result.

Your query will be:

```
SELECT d.doctor_id,
       sum(case when a.appt_date > 0 then 1 else 0 end) AppointmentCount 
FROM doctor d
left join appointment a  
on  d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id
group by d.doctor_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select d.doctor_id, count(a.app_date) as count
from doctor d left join appointment a on (d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id) 
group by d.doctor_id;
```

You can check the demo here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d62b3/4)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `distinct`: `GROUP BY` is already deduplicating the entries (because it's grouping by `doctor_id`.

The easiest way to do this is to use `left join`:

```
select d.doctor_id
     , count(a.appt_date) as appointmentCount
from doctor as d
     left join appointment as a on d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id
group by d.doctor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select doctor.doctor_id, nvl(count(appointment),0)
from doctor, appointment
where doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id(+)
group by doctor.doctor_id
```

outer join on appointment with doctor_id, group by doctor_id. use NVL in case no appointments for doctor so you can display zero